# Excel-Update Table using Extracted Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel with a lot of data and dates. Like this:

[image: first sheet with the data]

I open a second sheet and created a formula to extract data from the first sheet that fall between two dates. Like this:

[image: Second sheet with extracted data from the first sheet]

Now I want to be able to change the data on the new sheet and the old sheet will automatically get updated. For example I want to be able to change N to Y under Shipped and have the first sheet be updated to Y.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Comment: a formula will not do it, you will need vba.  And any data entry on the second sheet would break your formulas and they would need to be reapplied.  You should be using a database not Excel for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

please use VBA:
open VBA editor (ALT+F11), add new module and paste code below. 
**After enterering all corrections to your second sheet**, please run macro.

**It isn't optimal solution** but it should work:

```
Sub CopyChangesInSheepment()

 Set wksSheet1 = Worksheets("sheet1")   'put name of yours FIRST sheet here
 Set wksSheet2 = Worksheets("sheet2")   'put name of yours SECOND sheet here

 F = wksSheet1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 S = wksSheet2.Range("a6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 For j = 6 To S
   For i = 1 To F
      id1 = wksSheet1.Cells(i, 1)
      id2 = wksSheet2.Cells(j, 1)
      ord1 = wksSheet1.Cells(i, 8)
      ord2 = wksSheet2.Cells(j, 8)
      If id1 = id2 And ord1 = ord2 Then   'check if order number and sku are the same
         wksSheet1.Cells(i, 24) = wksSheet2.Cells(j, 15)   'column shipped is 24. column (X) in sheet1 and 15. (O) in sheet2
      End If
   Next i
 Next j

End Sub
```